# Zabbix trigger for high amount of MySQL connections

Tags: mysql, zabbix

I am trying to create a Zabbix trigger, which will fire an alarm, when there is a MySQL connection spike/ high amount of MySQL connections. Has someone created such trigger ?

Comment: Assuming you already have the item collecting this, what have you tried to use as the trigger expression and how did that fail?

Comment: It is just not reacting when there is a connection spike and I can't figure out why is that happening. If someone has a working trigger syntax, I will be glad to see it

Comment: The trigger syntax isn't a great issue, something like {server.mysqlconns:last(0)}>n} will do the trick... but how are you collecting the number of sql connections? Could you paste your item?

Comment: {my-mysql-server.com:grpsum["zabbix-group","mysql.connections",last].avg(6)}*5<{my-mysql-server.com:grpsum["zabbix-group","mysql.connections",last].last()}

Comment: and this does not fire any alarm. Where is the problem ?

Comment: The zabbix agent is "polling" the mysql server for the number of connections. If your polling intervall is 60 seconds, and the spike occurs inside the polling interval and goes down again before the next polling is done, zabbix won't see the spike. You can look at the graph of the number of connections if zabbix does see it or not

Comment: I see, the last reply is very useful, but what to put in the experssion constructor in order to check on every 30 seconds ? And where to put it exactly - "s0-29" probably ?

Answer (score 0):

Use [this template](https://share.zabbix.com/databases/mysql/template-mysql-800-items) to monitor mysql.
This template has multiple item for monitor mysql than an item show mysql connection, you can define your trigger on this.